# Регулярное выражение для логина C#

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, логин

Есть регулярное выражение

**^(?=.{8,24})(?=.+[0-9])[a-z][a-z0-9]*[._-]{1}[a-z0-9]+$**

Как добавить проверку на то чтоб была хотя бы одна заглавная буква?
И как можно данное выражение улучшить?

Условия этого регулярного выражения

1) Длина логина от 8 до 24 символов

2) Начало и конец с маленькой буквы или цифры

3) В логине должен быть только 1 символ . - или _

4) Также в логине должна быть хотя бы 1 цифра

5) И как минимум 1 заглавная буква

Comment: `^(?=.{8,24}$)(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[._-][a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-z0-9]$`?

Comment: Почти. В вашем регулярном выражении при проверке я выявил что логин должен начинаться только на маленькую букву а заканчиваться на цифру.
А нужно чтоб начало было как во 2 пункте.

Comment: Т.е. `^(?=.{8,24}$)(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])[a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*[._-][a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-z0-9]$`?

Comment: Да. Теперь можно ли как то его сделать проще?

Comment: И как это работает (?=[^0-9]*[0-9]) не совсем понял.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте

```
^(?=.{8,24}$)(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])[a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*[._-][a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-z0-9]$
```

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?=.{8,24}$)` - сразу после текущей позиции (т.е. в начале строки) должно быть от 8 до 24 любых символов, отлчных от символов перехода на новую строку
- `(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])` - сразу после текущей позиции (т.е. в начале строки) должно быть 0 и более символов, отличных от цифр, а затем цифра
- `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])` - сразу после текущей позиции (т.е. в начале строки) должно быть 0 и более символов, отличных от заглавных букв, а затем заглавная буква
- `[a-z0-9]` - буква в нижнем регистре или цифра
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` - 0 и более букв или цифр
- `[._-]` - точка, нижнее подчёркивание или дефис
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` - 0 и более букв или цифр
- `[a-z0-9]` - строчная буква или цифра
- `$` - конец строки.

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/rPSZTJ/1)

Comment: Надо наверно "список регулярок на все случаи жизни" )))))